# How to safely drop / delete a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to drop a table but I want to be 100% sure the table is unused first. How can I do so with complete certainty?

I've already:

- Made sure there are no references to the table in the codebase
- Dropped the table in the staging environment over a week ago
- Renamed the table in production (I appended _to_delete at the end) over a week ago
- Asked other engineers if table is needed

I suppose I can revoke permissions to the table from the application database user as a next step. What I would love is to be able to record table access to know for sure that table is not being referenced, but I wasn't able to find a way to do that over a specific timeframe.

And yes, I'm realize I'm being a bit paranoid (I could always restore the table from backup if it turns out it's needed) but I'm not a DBA so I'd prefer to be extra cautious.

Comment: Why not just rename it and see where the application breaks?

Comment: Something that is often overlooked and comes back to bite you later. Make sure you run any **Annual** processing, reports, cleanups, etc. in a test environment. It would not do for a process to die months later.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've done that. The problem is I'm not sure if that's a foolproof way of making sure it's safe to delete the table or not. It looks like you're a database expert - is renaming the table enough to be 100% confident that you can delete the table? (assuming you wait long enough for errors to show up of course)

Comment: @Belayer We don't have any annual processes thank god. The vast majority of our jobs are weekly so in this scenario I believe waiting over a week is adequate. Good advice though :)

Comment: If you renamed it, nothing can access the table with the old name. So from the perspective of the application it's the same as dropping it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a backup of the table and then drop the table, if application breaks then you always have the option to re-create it with the backup table.

Answer (score 0):

Paranoia is a virtue for a database administrator.

Revoking permissions seems like a good way to proceed.

To check if the table is used, observe the `seq_scan` and `idx_scan` columns of the `pg_stat_user_tables` entry for the table. If these values don't change, the table is not accessed. These values are not 100% accurate, since statistics are deliberately sent via a UDP socket, but if the numbers don't change at all, you can be pretty certain that the table is unused.